# saxutils.escape() escapes semicolon twice

Tags: python, sax

I'm trying to escape semicolon in by saxutils.escape method.

```
saxutils.escape('<;', {';': '&#59;'})
```

I expect it to produce

```
'&lt;&#59;'
```

But it gives

```
'&lt&#59;&#59;'
```

Is this by design? And how can I get my expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `saxutils.escape` works in two steps. First, it parses `<`, `>`, and `&`, then it uses `entities` to parse the **result** of that parsing.

So once `<` has been replaced by `&lt;`, you've got `&lt;;`, so you end up with `&lt&#59;&#59;`.

Basically, what it's doing makes sense. If you need to escape semicolons, it's not because of HTML reasons, so it must be to double-escape them. In this situation, it makes sense to escape the semicolons created by HTML-required escaping.

You can't get your desired result with `saxutils.escape`. You need to use another method of escaping. See the [Python Wiki page on escaping HTML](http://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml) for some ideas.

You can also use something like what is in my answer to [What is the best way to do a find and replace of multiple queries on multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992545/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-a-find-and-replace-of-multiple-queries-on-multiple-fil/6992774#6992774) to replace semicolons simultaneously with other patters so you don't double-substitute anything.

Comment: Then what is proper way to get my expected result?

Comment: See my update. There are some suggestions on the linked Python wiki page.

Answer (score 1):

That's because [escape()](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.utils.html#xml.sax.saxutils.escape) takes the final semicolon character of the escaped `&lt;` into account, and replaces it with `&#59;` as instructed. Therefore, `<;` gives `&lt&#59;&#59;`.

Semicolons normally do not need to be escaped that way, so I don't think it's a bug in the function, only an edge case with this specific character.

Comment: In my case, for security concerns, I'd like user's input of semicolon is escaped.

Comment: That won't be easy to do: you can do that neither upstream (because the initial ampersand character would be escaped), nor downstream (because the final semicolon character would be escaped). You can try character substitution, as Tim Pietzcker suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, and Frédéric Hamidi has explained why this is so.

So how can you get what you want?

Taking @agf's suggestion:

```
escape_table = {
    "&": "&amp;",
    ">": "&gt;",
    "<": "&lt;",
    ";": "&#59;",
    }

def escape(text):
    return "".join(escape_table.get(c,c) for c in text)
```

Comment: You'd be better off not using `saxutils.escape` at all than doing this.

Comment: It's user input -- some day, a user is going to put in some text containing your "special" character and it's going to mess things up.